# Running two python processes

Tags: python, python-2.7, interpreter, running-other-programs

I am running two python codes edited by two different text editors (Eclipse and Spyder), and from task manager I saw two python.exe processes. **Will these two processes interfere with each other?** I am worried because I used almost the same set of variable names across these two scripts and both codes are working on the same data input with very similar data structure.

Comment: No they will not, they have no idea each other exist. However, be careful if they try to touch the same files if you are doing I/O.

Comment: No, it's separated programs. You can even run the same script from the same editor (if it can) and they are treated as different programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The processes know nothing about each other.

It wouldn't matter if they were identical or not. Each process is allocated resources by the OS, so each process has its own resources, and they will not overlap. In fact, it is very common to use multiple similar Python processes to do multiprocessing when you have processing that can be done in parallel and logically allocated per process.

Unless they are both using a shared resource like a file, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @ZhiyiZhang you're welcome, if I answer your question, you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it and it will give you +2 to your rep by doing so.